# Intersection of descending series in a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, discrete-geometry, geometric-group-theory

I have stumbled upon a problem. It can be stated in the following way: Let $E$ be a finitely generated free group. Denote $\gamma_n(E)$ the $n$-th term of the lower central series. Consider a generator in this group $e\in E$. I am interested in finding subsets of the set $$\cap_{i=1}^\infty e\gamma_n(E).$$

I have tried the following approach: the set $e\gamma_n(E)$ is obviously a subset of $\langle e, \gamma_n(E)\rangle$. In the question [Intersection of subgroup of a free group with the lower central series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359426/intersection-of-subgroup-of-a-free-group-with-the-lower-central-series) I have seen an answer stated this way: the sequence $\langle S,\gamma_n(E)\rangle$ converges to $S$ iff $S$ is closed in the pronilpotent topology on the group $E$. However, it is not really clear whether $\{e\}$ is closed and, if not, how to compute the said intersection.

Comment: Singletons are closed on the pronilpotent topology  because free groups are residually finite p-groups

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you have in mind an article of some sort where I could read about this?

Comment: You can find that in lots of places.  The easiest proof is via the Magnus representation.  I think it is in Ribes and Zalesskii and probably it is in math overflow

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20471/why-are-free-groups-residually-finite

Comment: If John Conway is not your real name you might be asked to change the username (if your name is John Conway, you might consider adding a middle letter). [See this Meta question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3065/celebrity-usernames)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "generator" in a given group. Maybe you mean some element of a fixed free generating subset?

Comment: I have downloaded the book by Ribes and Zalesskii, thank you. 
Concerning generators: yes, I meant an element of a basis of $E$.

Comment: An(other) explicit reference for free groups being residually (finite $p$-groups) is Theorem 5.2 of Hall, Marshall [**A topology for free groups and related groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1969513), Ann. Math. (2) 52, 127-139 (1950). [ZBL0041.36210](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0041.36210).